# "will" or "would"

Tags: modal-verbs

What is the difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> Why don't you do the exam?
>
> I'm sure you **will** pass it.

or

> I'm sure you **would** pass it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is very slight, but as Alex says its about the difference between a real and a counter-factual situation.

> I'm sure you will pass it.

implies

> You are going to take it and you will pass it.
>
> I'm sure you would pass it.

implies

> If you decided to take it, you would pass it (but you might decide not to take it).

Answer (score 1):

It is "I'm sure you will pass it", the word "would" refers to a theoretical situation whilst your example is of a literal situation.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in meaning.

The use of would, instead of will,  makes the latter sentence less direct or blunt.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to edit a post, so I comment here. That's a typo "wi7ll" :)